# Scala Tuple of seq to seq of object

Tags: scala, slick

I am having tuples of format as `(DBIO[Seq[Person]], DBIO[Seq[Address]])` as one to one mapping. `Person` and `Address` is separate table in RDBMS. Profile definition is `Profile(person: Person, address: Address)`. Now I  want to convert the former into `DBIO[Seq[Profile]]`. Following is code snippet for how I have got `(DBIO[Seq[Person]], DBIO[Seq[Address]])`

```
        for {
          person <- personQuery if person.personId === personId
          address <- addressQuery if address.addressId === profile.addressId
        } yield (person.result, address.result)
```

Need help with this transformation to `DBIO[Seq[Profile]`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't use a join and you need to work with two actions (two `DBIO`s), what you can do is combine the two actions into a single one:

```
// Combine two actions into a single action
val pairs: DBIO[ ( Seq[Person], Seq[Address] ) ] = 
  (person.result).zip(address.result)
```

(`zip` is just one of [many combinators](https://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.html#combining) you can use to manipulate `DBIO`).

From there you can use `DBIO.map` to convert the pair into the datastructure you want.

For example:

```
// Use Slick's DBIO.map to map the DBIO value into a sequence of profiles:
val profiles: DBIO[Seq[Profile]] = pairs.map { case (ppl, places) => 
  // We now use a regular Scala `zip` on two sequences:
  ppl.zip(places).map { case (person, place) => Profile(person, place) }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am unfamiliar with whatever DBIO is. Assuming it is a case class of some type T :

```
val (DBIO(people), DBIO(addresses)) = for {
  person <- personQuery if person.personId === personId
  address <- addressQuery if address.addressId === profile.addressId
} yield (person.result, address.result)

val profiles = DBIO(people.zip(addresses).map{ case (person, address) => Profile(person, address)})
```

Comment: Hi Terry! DBIO is a database context: there's no `get` on it: you run it at some point to get a result.

Comment: Understood. I guess the rest of my code is still relevant